# Client Socket Program throwing an exception

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2008

I have developed a socket Client/Server programs by using the below links

Server Socket Code:                                                     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Client Socket Code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

After my development, I have created a service for the server program and deployed it on  windows 8 server. When I tried to connect the  server program  from my development machine (Win 7) using the client ,  I got the below exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.80.33.77:8000
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at EODClient.AsyncClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

The client code throwing the exception

```
   private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try
    {
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        client.EndConnect(ar); //Throwing an Exception here

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

I  tested both client  and server on the same computer, but I got the same exception.

But the below scenario, the above code worked fine.

1. Started the service using Visual Studio 2008 on debug mode, Started the client from Windows 8 server
2. Started the service using Visual Studio 2008 on debug mode, Started the client from the same development machine

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In your example, server listens to port 11000, but your error message says you try to connect to port 8000

Comment: if both are on same server than this 10.80.33.77:8000 should be 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @EhsanUllah from question: *I have created a service for the server program and deployed it on windows 8 server. When I tried to connect the server program from my development machine (Win 7) using the client*

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, my code was listening the port 8000. Also from the same server , I am using the port 8000. Provided the computer name as the Host

Comment: Have you configured the firewall on server machine?

Comment: @EhsanUllah ports can not be pinged. Machines can be pinged and `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` message says target machine is alive....

Comment: @I4V sorry i meant telnet

Comment: @Ehsam Ullah, telnet to the server machine failed.. Connecting To 10.80.33.77:8000...Could not open connection to the host, on 23: Connect failed

Comment: @Ullan telnet expects ip and port separated by a space, not a colon. So you should try `telnet 10.80.33.77 8000`

Answer (score 0):

In the Socket server code, I have created the thread inside the Main method. But after  deployed it to the server, the thread start code never getting called.

Finally I moved the thread code to the OnStart method as similar to the below and it worked fine.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
    thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc);
    thread.Name = "My Worker Thread";
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
 }
```

The below post helped to resolve the issue:
[Windows Service to run constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly)

Sorry for not copying the core(issue) part of code.The code was working with the debugger, so I never doubted the above code which was called from the Main function.