# Prevent WindowsService exiting

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service (my first one) that checks database regularly using a timer and converts video files if there are any queued.
But when I start service it just exits as there is nothing to do at the moment.
what can I do to put service in a kind of Idle mode that just stays running?

Comment: well `while (true)` will be infinite loop my timer will never be triggered, I think there must be a better way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Service to run constantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly)

Comment: nope Windows [Service to run constantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly) is not the answer because it doesn't exit until there is nothing to do. I want to keep the service alive even if there is nothing to do.

Comment: I don't think you read the answers. Checking the database is "something to do," it's your timer event. You just have to have a way to make sure your program lives until the next timer event is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
OnStart()
{
  while(!serviceNotStopped)
  {
   <do stuff, create threads >
    <Sleep if required>
  }

 <stop signal for all child thread if any >
}




 OnStop()
 {
  serviceNotStopped = true;
 }
```

Comment: This is the *wrong* way to do it.  The `OnStart` method is a callback function from the Service Control Manager, and it needs to return in a timely fashion.  Typically, you'd start a timer or kick off a thread to do the work of the service.