# Basic design pattern for using TPL inside windows service for C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I am trying to build up windows service which need some kind of parallelism for pooling files from different ftp sources. For starting multiple ftp downloads I am looking in TPL library to easily do foreach loops and making parallelism totally easy. But when I search how to start or stop my service(s), best shot I fund is to make new threads inside `OnStart()` method, as it is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865893/69433

Reading about TPL there is always note that TPL is more advanced than manual threading and manual stop threading.

I did not find any sample post which describes how to make TPL loop inside WindowsService ?

My code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
     _thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc);
     _thread.Name = "My Worker Thread";
     _thread.IsBackground = true;
     _thread.Start();
}
```

And inside `WorkerThreadFunc` to do sme kind of TPL

```
private void WorkerThreadFunc()
{
foreach (string path in paths)
{
    string pathCopy = path;
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Boolean taskResult = ProcessPicture(pathCopy);
            return taskResult;
        });
    task.ContinueWith(t => result &= t.Result);
    tasks.Add(task);
}

}
```

Or I should start my WorkerThreadFunc also as TASK ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Caveat here is not only how you *start* your worker, but also how you actually *stop* it.

Beside Task itself, TPL also provides you with a very convenient way of *task cancellation* by using `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` objects.

### Starting and stopping windows service with TPL

To apply this technique to your Windows Service, you basically need to do the following:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private Task backgroundTask;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellation = tokenSource.Token;
        backgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WorkerThreadFunc(cancellation),
                                    cancellation,
                                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                                    TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

Notes:

- `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` hints a task scheduler that this task may require a separate thread and avoids putting it on a ThreadPool (so that it won't block other items in a pool)
- `CancellationToken` is passed to WorkerThreadFunc because this is the way it will be notified to stop its work - see Cancellation section below

And in your OnStop method, you trigger cancellation and wait for task to complete:

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        bool finishedSuccessfully = false;
        try
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            finishedSuccessfully = backgroundTask.Wait(timeout);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (finishedSuccessfully == false)
            {
                // Task didn't complete during reasonable amount of time
                // Fix your cancellation handling in WorkerThreadFunc or ProcessPicture
            }
        }
    }
```

### Cancellation

By calling `tokenSource.Cancel();` we simply tell every `CancellationToken` issued by this `tokenSource` to become cancelled and every method that accepted such token (like your WorkerThreadFunc) should now be *stopping* its work.

Handling cancellation is specific to the implementation, but general rule is that your method should be monitoring cancellation token state and **be able to stop its work in a reasonable amount of time**. This approach requires you to *logically* split your work into smaller parts so that you won't stuck at doing some work that needs a lot of time to complete and won't start any new work if cancellation was requested.

Looking at your WorkerThreadFunc code, you may consider to check for cancellation *before* you execute every new `ProcessPicture` task, for example:

```
private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

private void WorkerThreadFunc(CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // you may also want to pass a timeout value here to handle 'stuck' processing
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            // no more new tasks
            break;
        }

        string pathCopy = path;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Boolean taskResult = ProcessPicture(pathCopy, token); // <-- consider a cancellation here
                return taskResult;
            }, token); // <<--- using overload with cancellation token
        task.ContinueWith(t => result &= t.Result);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
}
```

If `ProcessPicture` takes very long time to complete, you may also want to add cancellation support in there. Similarly to WorkerThreadFunc, you should take into account `ProcessPicture` implementation. The key idea here is to find a place where you can *safely* stop doing work and return from method. By *safely* I mean - **without** leaving system or data in a broken state.

In addition to monitoring `IsCancellationRequested` in WorkerThreadFunc, you can also [`Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) a callback that will be executed when cancellation is requested, to do some other stuff like cleanup, etc:

```
token.Register(CancellationCallback);
```

And

```
private void CancellationCallback()
{
    // wait for all tasks to finish

    // cleanup
}
```

Comment: +1000 thanx a lot, One more thing, Shoud I use same CancellationToken for child tasks to safe stop procesign picures ? Shoud OnStop() method do backgroundTask.Wiat(3000); ?

Comment: Yes, usually it is safe to re-use the same cancellation token for child tasks (unless you need some different cancellation behavior for them). For OnStop - yes, I meant instance [Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Updated code for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, what is a tasks object in the Task.WaitAll(tasks);? And how would I pass a timeout value here?

Comment: Also, what does task.ContinueWith(t => result &= t.Result); do? Does it simply accumulate whether all ProcessPicture tasks have been successful? And lastly, what is the purpose of Task.Factory.StartNew inside a foreach loop (in WorkerThreadFunc)? Why not just use Parallel.ForEach straight away?

Comment: The object you pass into `WaitAll` should be `Task[]`, `tasks` property can be of type `List<Task>`. To pass a timeout, use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235688(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Comment: Code in `ContinueWith` here defines something that should be done with the result after task has completed its execution. I took that code from the original question just to show complete example, your implementation may not need this.

Comment: Depending on which parts of this code are copied and pasted, there is a potentially nasty bug here. `Task.Factory.StartNew` does not return the Task from `WorkerThreadFunc`, and in fact does not support async delegates at all. This means that `backgroundTask` will have "completed" after the first use of  `await` inside `WorkerThreadFunc`. (Contrary to most people's expectations). The solution is to use the `Unwrap()` extension method on the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which lifts out the Task you're really interested in.

Comment: Two additional warnings: 1) I've found that OnStop is never called if the backgroundThread exits, and consequently added backgroundThread.ContinueWIth that calls base.Stop().  2)It's debatable that "LongRunning" should be used here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html