# How to prevent a custom thread crashing the windows service in .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

Consider the following snippet. The thread spawned by the main windows service thread will crash because it tries to open a null path. Then the crashing of the windows service will follow.

```
namespace ThreadCrashService {
class Program {
    public const string ServiceName = "ThreadCrashServiceTest";
    private static Timer _timer = null;
    private static int _timerInterval = 60000;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (!Environment.UserInteractive) {
            // running as service
            using (var service = new Service1()) System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(service);
        } else {
            string parameter = string.Concat(args);
            switch (parameter) {
                case "--install":
                    if (IsServiceInstalled()) {
                        UninstallService();
                    }

                    InstallService();
                    break;
                case "--uninstall":
                    if (IsServiceInstalled()) {
                        UninstallService();
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    Program program = new Program();
                    program.Start();
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void InstallService() {
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
    }

    private static bool IsServiceInstalled() {
        return System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices().Any(s => s.ServiceName == ServiceName);
    }

    private static void UninstallService() {
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
    }

    public void Start() {
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ThreadMethodThatWillCrash());
            thread.Start();
        } catch {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    public void ThreadMethodThatWillCrash() {            
        // ArgumentNullException
        File.Open(null, FileMode.Open);
    }
}
```

}

I know in windows form application, we can use

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
```

and

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

to catch the global exceptions not handled by UI threads. But for a console application, we can only use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

to log the exception. But this is not able to prevent the thread crashing the windows service. What else can I do to prevent the thread crashing the windows service? I can't change the way how the thread is created because it's a in a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the main thread to spool up Tasks from TPL in order to preserve the state of the process.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27384788/376550

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx