# Killing a .NET 4 Task?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Can I kill a [.NET 4.0 Task object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) with some method like we could with the old and dangerous [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) as discussed in the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051838/killing-a-thread-c) (pun intended and save the kittens!)

Kenny

Comment: duplicated item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/is-it-possible-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method

Comment: I know it's dangerous, but can it be done? I guess you're saying no.

Comment: @kenny Not without a lot of knowledge about the `Task` - If you knew, in advance, that the `TaskScheduler` being used was using a dedicated thread for the `Task`, you could call `Abort` on that thread.  That being said, it'd be a VERY bad idea to design a system that way.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I agree it's bad design, but it's out of my hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Task` class is designed, and intended, to use the new [Cooperative Cancellation model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) of .NET 4 instead of relying on a destructive "abort" style of cancellation.

There is no direct way to cancel a `Task` (like `Thread.Abort()`, though that's *very bad* to use in any case), but there is an entire framework in place to provide the tooling to [request that the Task cancel itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that CancelationTokenSource and the cooperative method how it should be done, but I have a case where I need to Abort the task (talking to 3rd party hardware API) and I'm willing to go unstable to do it. THanks again!.

Comment: @kenny There's no mechanism in `Task` to allow this.

Comment: @kenny, `Thread` is not deprecated, it's just that most of the time, `Task`s are more convenient.

Comment: it is possible to provide provide a Task's Thread.Abort as a delegate for the cancellation token: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715122/571637

Comment: @jltrem That's a very, very bad idea, though.  Your aborting a ThreadPool thread, which can lead to very bad behavior in the entire system.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Agreed, which is why I said "don't do this".  But the answer to "can I do it?" is "yes".

Comment: @jltrem You're actually not cancelling the Task, though -you're killing it's underlying thread (there is a difference, at least in the way I look at it)

Comment: This makes no sense. If there's a Task that hangs indefinitely or would hang indefinitely, due to a logic error or something, in production code, such as a processing queue... there MUST be a way to terminate the Task. Otherwise, they would start an operation, continue to accumulate in memory, as more and more start to run forever, with no way to cancel them. Even if the framework could cancel it's scheduled jobs, it couldn't cancel the Task itself. This seems like a huge flaw. Also, Thread.Abort exists. It's a thing. ThreadAbortExceptions are a thing, and they're triggered by ASP.NET recycle.