# When shutting down the application, not all windows are closed

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have an application, where a create a new window for my graphic. I create it next way:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var win = new MyWindow();
    win.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

The problem is, that when I close Main application, additional window is still on and I need to close it manually. I set  **ShutDownMode** in my `App.xaml` to `OnMainWindowClose` and overrided `OnClosed`:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

But it does not help me.

Comment: Try `Environment.Exit(0);` or `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Comment: Do you need the ApartmentState ? Isn't it responsible for this behavior ?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM that is a way to make sure the application stops, but that is the brutal way and not the most clean way.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM although it is a valid answer:)

Comment: But...why are you doing it this way? You are effectively spawning a new application by doing this. Is that *really* what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rikalous what do you mean by "You are effectively spawning a new application by doing this"? Isn't it just a new window? Why do I spawn new application?

Comment: @Sasha because you are creating the window on a new thread, it is now independent from the calling application. See answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
thread.IsBackground = true;
```

before run the thread.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

Comment: Could someone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: @C4stor A background thread will not prevent process to shut down.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your thread(s) is/are stopped, before the application exits.
You could do this by using Thread.Abort or wait for it using Thread.Join.

But those are nasty ways to end or wait for a thread. The best way is to use a bool to stop it from running.

Here is how to stop your thread the "Clean" way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664959/1661209

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but setting threat.IsBackground = true also helped)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to establish a relationship between windows you should set the Owner property of the new window thus:

```
var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
childWindow.Owner = this;
childWindow.Show();
```

Now, if you close the main window, all its children will close too.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the thread that you spawn and when exiting the application, you signal the thread to exit somewhow (perhaps via a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)). After that you have to wait for the thread to exit by joining it.

```
_thread.Join();
```