# abort thread in the sub form C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

the main form will create another form, the sub new form will create a Thread at loading.
when the user close the sub form, I make event handler for closed form to abort its Thread.

but when the user try to close the main form the Thread of the sub form still running, how to abort it either the user close the sub form or the main form.

Comment: *Never `Abort()` a thread.* Find a way to signal it to exit gracefully.  (A simple flag, a `ManualResetEvent`, etc.)

Comment: While closing the parent form just fire an event to close all child forms. In the event handler do your thing.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart
why you don't recommend to abort Threads ?

Comment: @Hanaa because it can leave your program in a inconsistent state. See [this answer for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051838/killing-a-thread-c/1051854#1051854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [IsBackground()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the Thread to True.  This will allow it to be shutdown automatically when the application exits.